# Redirect http request to another address

Tags: delphi, httprequest, redirect, fiddler, http-redirect

I have a software that was developed in delphi and that makes a http get request to a specific url that I want to redirect to another url. 
I have the source code but I can't recompile it because it wasn't developed by me, so it would take too much effort and time, and right now I can't afford it.

Anyway, back to my problem.

I tried using fiddler 2. It worked, but only for when I try accessing the url via browser. When my application sends the requests, it doesn't get redirected to the new url.
Does anyone have any other suggestion of what I can do?

Comment: If you cannot edit the delphi source code, a possible solution (the easiest I can think) is an apache .htaccess file with a RewriteRule ON that maps the old url to the new one that you need. This of course implies that you have apache and you are able to rewrite a regex for the new rule

Comment: This is used in REST services. For example instead of accessing www.site.com/rest/index.php you can use apache so that the link www.site.com/api/main/ redirects to the previous link. Of course this is permanent (not like in fiddler) since it's server side and managed by apache

Comment: I'm not sure if I got it but I think the problem is that the old url is from a webservice that was taken down. It is not, nor was it before, running in a server of my own.